# How to get userid from previous page and update that record?

Tags: asp.net

In my application there is edit button on click on it user will navigate to edit page with userid .
This navigation working properly.
but on edit page that user id should store in local variable and update the data by update query where userid=local variable.
How to store userid in local database?

Comment: You can take a look at this to retrieve variable from query string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Is there any other code sample?

Comment: Google using the keywords in that article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the UserID in session variable as follows...

```
session["UserID"]=UserID;
```

After Creating the Session variable,redirect to the next page...

After that in the next page you can access the session variable in page load...

```
string UserID=session["UserID"].tostring();
```

Please mark as answer if it satisfies...

Comment: seesion does not exist in current context error coming

Comment: You are redirecting to the page using a button click,right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query string or session for that and retrieve it on the redirected page.